# Ubuntu on developer mode of Toshiba CB35-B3340 Chromebook 2

Tags: system-installation, chromebook

Has anybody tried the Ubuntu on the Chromebook Developer mode of the new Toshiba CB35-B3340 Chromebook 2?

As far as I know, this Intel Bay-Trail laptop is on sale from November 2014 in the US, maybe in other countries as well, and it is a straight Google Chromebook, so potentially it is only a matter of following the instructions here:

https://sites.google.com/site/chromeoswikisite/home/what-s-new-in-dev-and-beta/developer-mode

As of today (2014-12-09) there does not seem to be a way to legacy-boot Bay-Trail computers, so the only way to install a fully-fledged Linux seems to be [crouton](https://github.com/dnschneid/crouton).

This may change in the future, but who knows when.

Anybody?

Answer (score 2):

Yes! I'm very satisfied with Ubuntu 14.04.1 LTS on my Toshiba CB35-B3340 Chromebook 2, installed via crouton. I've been using it regularly for a couple months. I produce [my podcast](http://j.mp/1FWGrMj) with it. I agree with Wade that 16GB is a little cramped.  I bought a 128GB SD this week. Now I can store my media locally. Ubuntu prompts me for a password to mount it, even though it's already mounted, whenever I return from ChromeOS. All I have to do is close the dialog, though. Minor annoyance.

It's also inconvenient that there is no native (free) Linux Drive client. I work around that by using Dropbox for all my cloud storage needs that the Chromium browser Google Drive app lacks (e.g. mounting the local copy so I can manipulate files from the OS).

I don't have all keys working yet.

Answer (score 1):

I have installed Ubuntu 15.04 installed by using a modified BIOS to be able to boot to a live USB drive. This means that I have a full installation of Ubuntu and I have to say it's fast and really works well. [I created a 5 step installation guide that I hope helps anyone else](http://www.fascinatingcaptain.com/chromebook/install-ubuntu-on-the-toshiba-chromebook-2-in-5-steps/)

Answer (score 0):

I'm currently typing my answer on a Toshiba CB35-B3340. It's amazing. Honestly. The only thing I can complain about is that 16GB SSD is difficult to manage but other than that. Excellent choice. I love it.

Comment: That's not an answer.

Answer (score 0):

I used to code on Windows, but 2 years ago my buddy showed me Ubuntu. 
You guess? I'm still using it!)

Not a secret, that Ubuntu works much faster, than Windows. Linux is Linux)
That's why, SSD drive inside is just "flying in the sky":)

As for the laptop itself, it copes with all objectives on Ubuntu. 
http://cent.im/popular/259/toshiba_chromebook_2